# Using remember picture with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The two rectangles in the example plot, by my reckoning, should overlap exactly. I would be most grateful if somebody could explain why they don't! My presumption is that this is a bug in my TikZ version (2.10), however downloading the latest TikZ didn't alleviate the problem.

Thanks

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

Version (\pgfversion)

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) };
\coordinate (X) at (axis cs:0.5,0.5);
\node [anchor=north east, draw, inner sep=5mm, red] at (axis cs:0.5,0.5){};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node [anchor=north east, dashed, draw, inner sep=5mm, green] at (X) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of document]

Comment: Well they do overlap on my system. Can you include the screenshot with faulty alignment? Did you run twice?

Comment: I can confirm that I ran it twice:

  for X in 1 2 ; do TEXMFHOME=~/tmp/tikz/tex/ pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex ; done

Comment: You need to remove the second `anchor=north east` then they should overlap. I don't know why I didn't mention it in the first place, I need some coffee I guess.

Comment: If you use the newest version it works out of the box. Here the relevant part of my listed files: `pgfplots.sty    2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29)
    tikz.sty    2012/08/29 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.100)`

Comment: Seems to be a pgfplots bug that's been resolved.  I reproduced the issue in pgfplots 1.6; when I updated to the TeXLive version (1.7) it went away.

Answer (score 3):

The comments from Matthew Leingang and Marco Daniel were correct: updating to the latest version of PGFPlots solved the problem. I had tried this previously, but to no avail. This is because I had used the method of setting TEXMFHOME to the directory containing the latest version. For whatever reason, this didn't work. Using TEXINPUTS, as described on page 9 of the pgfplots manual, did work.

Thanks for the help,